# Short fiction story based on the Doctrine of the Gospel: man dies baptizing a robot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago a friend shared with me his copy of a book that contained short fiction stories based on Doctrine of the Gospel of Jesus Christ.

One story was about a man who, being adamant to share the Gospel with everyone he could, died of electrocution attempting to baptize a robot.

Comment: Hi there. Roughly how long ago is "years ago"? Three years? The 60s?